# Javascript spinning circle animation while loading page does not stop

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

So I have been sitting on this for a few hours, but can't seem to figure out why my code does not work.

I am trying to make an animation of a 'spinning circle' (or simular) while my page loads. And what I have so far basically does that, but my problem is that it does not stop, so the rest of my page does not load.

**Javascript:**

```
// Wait for window load
$(window).load(function() {
    // Animate loader off screen
    $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");;
});
```

**HTML:**
Basically just a div with a class like

```
<div class="se-pre-con"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.no - js# loader {
    display: none;
}

.js# loader {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100 px;
    top: 0;
}

.se - pre - con {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0 px;
    top: 0 px;
    width: 100 %;
    height: 100 %;
    z - index: 9999;
    background: url(images / loader - 64 x / Preloader_2.gif) center no - repeat# fff;
}
```

*NOTE:* I used this tutorial: https://smallenvelop.com/display-loading-icon-page-loads-completely/

*OTHER NOTE:* I am writing this for an ASP.NET MVC application

Comment: did you check your console log? What are you getting in your console log?

Comment: Wow, I'm stupid, forgot about that. It gives me the reference error `$ is not defined`. Probably something really stupid now that I know what goes wrong

Comment: never mind. Enjoy coding!

Comment: haha, thanks, will do that

Comment: `$ is not defined` you gotta include jQuery :)

Comment: Is your issue fixed then? If you're still getting the same error you're not linking jquery correctly

Comment: Yeah, figured it out now. @Gezzasa Indeed, I was calling the script before the Render for jQuery. Really simple thing I missed, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this was a really simple fix. Basically I just called my script before rendering my jQuery. My header looked like this before:

```
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/LoadSpinner.js">
</script>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - DeviceManagment</title>
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
</script>
    </head>
```

All I had to do, is call my Javascript file after the Renders for my jQuery.

Really simple solution, but still hope it helps someone out there.